# Parcel Chrome Extension build causes an unsafe-eval error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, parcel

I am building a [Chrome Extension with Parcel](https://parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/). Development is fine, but when running `npm run build`, and loading the `dist` folder, the popup for my extension is just a white screen. When inspecting it, I get the error:

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is
> not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security
> Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'".

Idk why it only happens during the build process and not during development (I have seen this same error in development with a similar codebase using other extension frameworks). How can I avoid this error while still generating a build `dist` folder?

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: I'm still working on it but I think it's this: 1 of your sub-dependencies uses eval. First you have to find the dependencies that causes the unsafe-eval issue. Once u find it (or however many cause the issue), clone its repo and install their dependencies. Then search their node_modules folder (disable it from being excluded from search or open the node_modules folder itself in a new window) for eval. Once you verify that 1 of ur dependencies has a dependency that uses eval, replace it. I'm not sure if tree shaking can be done before bundling, but  that could shake out code that uses eval.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the pointer!